# Select attribute from xml element

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to select an attribute from my root node but i keep getting a null exception on the select part.

What's the correct way of getting the value of my attribute?

The value i am trying to get value of the attribute: SymbolicName

The xml document:

```
<Bundle xmlns="urn:uiosp-bundle-manifest-2.0" Name="ContactUsPlugin" SymbolicName="ContactUsPlugin" Version="1" InitializedState="Active">
  <Activator Type="ContactUsPlugin.Activator" Policy="Immediate" />
  <Runtime>
    <Assembly Path="bin\ContactUsPlugin.dll" Share="false" />
  </Runtime>

  <Functionality>
    <Controller>About</Controller>
    <View>Index</View>
  </Functionality>

  <Scripts>
    <Script version="1">
      <Location>E:\Git Projects\Kapsters\Plugins\ContactUsPlugin\Sql\Sql1.txt</Location>
    </Script>
    <Script version="2">
      <Location>E:\Git Projects\Kapsters\Plugins\ContactUsPlugin\Sql\Sql1.txt</Location>
    </Script>
  </Scripts>
</Bundle>
```

I tried:

```
  string widgetCodeName =
            (from db in ManifestDocument.Elements() select db.Attribute("SymbolicName").Value).First();

   string widgetCodeName =
            (from db in ManifestDocument.Descendants() select db.Element("Bundle").Attribute("SymbolicName").Value).First();

  string widgetCodeName =
            (from db in ManifestDocument.Element("Bundle").Attributes() where db.Name == "SymbolicName" select db.Value).First();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this examples work depending on if you need only the value or the XAttribute itself:

```
XDocument ManifestDocument = XDocument.Load("YourXmlFile.xml");

var myquery = ManifestDocument.Elements().Attributes("SymbolicName").First();//the XAttribute

string myvalue = ManifestDocument.Root.Attribute("SymbolicName").Value;//the value itself

var secondquery = ManifestDocument.Descendants().Attributes("SymbolicName").First();//another way to get the XAttribute
```

The last one (secondquery) will get SymbolicName attribute even if also defined in another node if you remove the .First().

Answer (score 2):

According to the xml that you have, the bundle tag is the root node. Try:

```
string widgetCodeName = ManifestDocument.Root.Attribute("SymbolicName").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

if this is your entire XML then you can get it with the code below.

```
XElement elem = XElement.Parse(xmlStr);
string val = elem.Attribute("SymbolicName").Value;
```

where xmlStr is your XML. if the attribute is missing then the Attribute method will return null so make sure you test for null before accessing the Value property

Answer (score 0):

Your `Bundle` element has a xml namespace. You need to specify it:

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:uiosp-bundle-manifest-2.0";

string widgetCodeName = (string)ManifestDocument
                          .Element(ns + "Bundle")
                          .Attribute("SymbolicName");
```

Or, if `Bundle` is your `Root` element you can do:

```
string widgetCodeName = (string)ManifestDocument
                          .Root
                          .Attribute("SymbolicName");
```

Comment: And how can i select the Path attribute in the element Assembly?

Comment: ManifestDocument.Root.Attribute("SymbolicName").Value is actually much better than casting it explicitly.

Comment: @bLaXjack no, casting is better because `.Value` will throw an exception if the attirubute wasn't found

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:uiosp-bundle-manifest-2.0";
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(@"xmlDocument");


var assemblyLocation = from a in xd.Descendants(ns + "Bundle")
                               select new
                               {
                                   Path = a.Element(ns + "Runtime").Element(ns + "Assembly").Attribute("Path").Value,
                               };
```